# Catch server side API calls in postman inspector - localhost

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, restsharp, postman

Is there a way to catch server side API calls in postman in my local machine?

All client side requests will be captured into postman by using "Inspector". I am wondering whether there is anything like that for server side api calls.

I am guessing it would not be possible when server is somewhere but should be possible for localhost?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear to me, what you are trying yo do?

Comment: By "API calls", do you mean rest-based calls from service to service on the same host? You would be able to catch those provided you're sitting between the two services on the same machine. If postman is an application that lets you formulate requests and interprets the response then it probably cannot catch two arbitrary other programs communicating.

Comment: Yes, by API calls i mean rest-based calls from my local website code to third party api services. Postman captures the request to the local website. I needs all the calls to be captured which are happening on local website code. @div Lasse

Comment: @DheerajPalagiri Okay, so i understand the scenario is like, you have a website on your local machine and that website call third party API and you want to capture that call in a postman. isn't it?

Comment: @Div exactly! calls made form javascript will be automatically captured. I am trying to find a way to capture all API calls made in c# code.

Comment: @DheerajPalagiri, If I'm not wrong, then you get that all call in your console, but i don't think you can get that in a postman.

Comment: @div when u say console do u mean "chrome developer tools -console" even there i can see only one server call (to the website) but not all subsequent calls made by the server call?

Comment: @DheerajPalagiri, Yes, make sure you try to find out in network tab.